# Using Netty 4, how do I write a handler that can inject messages on a periodic basis and still pass messages through?

Tags: netty

I am trying to write a class that injects a message into a channel every minute. I have figured out how to accomplish this using the code below, but I think my flush method is wrong. After flushing upstream messages, I am noticing the socket gets immediately closed.

```
public class Pinger extends ChannelOutboundMessageHandlerAdapter<ByteBuf> {
    private static final ByteBuf DUMMY = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("DUMMY".getBytes());

    @Override
    public void connect(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, SocketAddress remoteAddress, SocketAddress localAddress, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception{
        super.connect(ctx, remoteAddress, localAddress, promise);

        ctx.executor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new RepeatTask(ctx), 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private final class RepeatTask implements Runnable {
        private final ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

        public RepeatTask(ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(ctx.channel().isActive()){
                ctx.write(DUMMY.copy());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
        ctx.nextOutboundMessageBuffer().add(msg);
        ctx.flush();
    }
}
```

I would to also note that this handler is in the middle of a complex pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out how to make this work. ChannelStateHandlerAdapter is a much better class to inherit from.

```
public class Pinger extends ChannelStateHandlerAdapter {
    private static final ByteBuf DUMMY = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("DUMMY".getBytes());

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.fireChannelActive();
        ctx.executor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new PingTask(ctx), 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private final class RepeatTask implements Runnable {
        private final ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

        public RepeatTask(ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(ctx.channel().isActive()){
                ctx.write(DUMMY.copy());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)
            throws Exception {
        ctx.fireInboundBufferUpdated();
    }
}
```